# Cannot modify a job in SQL 2008 R2. The Modify window simply doesn't come up

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, jobs, maintenance-plans

I created a maintenance plan to perform daily backups with transaction log backups to be scheduled on four hour increments, however, I did not enable the job immediately, nor did I enter add the schedules.

Now I want to go into the maintenance plan and add the schedules for the full backup and the log backs, and to enable them. However, when I right click on the Maint. Plan and select "Modify" nothing happens. No dialogue box, nothing.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this buggy issue? Is this a known issue? My boss won't let me run any service packs. All their servers are straight 2008 R2 out of the box. No service packs. And I am not permitted to apply any at this time.

Comment: does it happen only when you try to edit that created plan or if you try to create a new one the wizard window will not show either? Is there a reason for not applying the updates on the server?

Comment: This looks related: https://paulgrevink.wordpress.com/2011/05/15/ms-sql-2008-r2-issue-impossible-to-modify-a-maintenance-plan/